# How to get model and product collection in magento 2

Tags: magento2

How to load the model in magento 2
like

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load()
```

as we used to get in magento 1.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this for get all product collection

```
<?php

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');

$collection = $productCollection->create()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->load();

foreach ($collection as $product){
     echo 'Name  =  '.$product->getName().'<br>';
}  

?>
```

Comment: <?php  
         $productId = 8;
         $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework   \App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
         $currentproduct = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
          echo $currentproduct->getName(); 
          ?>

Comment: It returns []. Why ?

Answer (score 25):

It is recommended to use dependency injection rather than directly using object Manager. Example:
In your block file you can use following code to return product collection:

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {

        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
public function getProductCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        return $collection;
    }
```

Comment: This is the correct approach using dependency injection. +1

Comment: Hi @Manashvi, i wants to fecth these product/cache/1d4ec593232a3f40f7a929d5b10820a2/u/g/ug03-bk-0.jpg images

Comment: @shivashankarm first of all, why? it's in cache, if you ever clear cache then the URL has changed and so has everything else. I suspect you've figured this by now but you shouldnt ever be referencing images stored in cache